# Server Certificate callback not compile properly

Tags: vb.net, web-services

I am calling one web service `claimServiceClient.AddClaim` passing login, claim (xml created) and the error Message. Somehow I am not getting `claimNbr` back which I am suppose to get (web service is working file which I tested already).

The same code work fine in other system, but when I am running `System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (Function(sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) True)`, its giving me an error:

> Nested function does not have the same signature as delegate 'Delegate Function RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(sender As Object, certificate As System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate, chain As System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain, sslPolicyErrors As System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors) As Boolean'

I've tried:

```
Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = Function(sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) True
```

It's also giving me the same error. Now I am not sure why its giving me this error on my system and not in other system. Do I need to add something to get this code work?

Comment: Set 'Option Strict On'

Comment: @SamMakin how I will do that ?

Comment: Put it at the top of the file.  You can also enable it in the project settings. It is pretty much always a good idea. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement

Comment: got it..........

Comment: Still the not compiling

Comment: You will have to fix the errors that result in applying the setting.  Presumably you are late binding all over the place, which results in this type of error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing it that way, you can also try doing it this way:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = New System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(Function()
                                                                                                                                         Return True
                                                                                                                                     End Function)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting 'Option Strict On'

Put it at the top of the file or enable it in the project settings. It is pretty much always a good idea.

You will have to fix the errors that result in applying the setting. Presumably you are late binding all over the place, which results in this type of error.

More info here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement